# Center align a <p> in <div>

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have the following CSS:

```css
#slot {
    width: 70px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: #00ffee;
    padding: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#element {
    text-align: center;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="slot">
    <p id="element">100 </p>
</div>
```

I would like the `<div>` to be of fixed size, and whatever number is in `<p>` (only numbers will be inserted there), I would like to have them centered right in the middle without changing the size of the bigger `<div>`.

I already set the `height` of the div to what I want, but having `line-height` in there has an advantage and a disadvantage. The advantage is that the number finally appears centered right in the middle. The disadvantage is that when I remove the number (it's an empty `<p>`), the `<div>`'s height shrinks.

How can I achieve my goal?

EDIT:
I used min-height and that fixed the issue. My issue now is that the content of the div doesn't appear in the middle and is cut like this:

[image: slot]

Why is this happening? This is very weird because jsfiddle shows it correctly.

**Happens on all browsers**.

Comment: Have you tried to set text-align: center; in #slot?

Comment: seems to work in chrome? http://jsfiddle.net/rhoenig/qXvag/ are you only seeing the issue in a specific browser?

Comment: Works here (FF 11, Ubuntu): http://jsfiddle.net/AHxRC/

Comment: In what browser the "height shrinks"? Because I tested and works the same with and without value for `p` for chrome 17,firefox 10,ie 7,8,9

Comment: try setting the div min-height, that may fix it shrinking when the content is removed.

Comment: Happens on all browsers.

Comment: The picture you show looks like my browsers did when I allowed them to add their default margins to p's. Set #element's margin to 0 first.

Comment: Works! why did this happen? Why did it work in jsfiddle?

Comment: Dear see my answer and let me know if issues is not fixed so i can work on your issue.

Comment: See the fiddle for demo and if you remove the value div will not shrink.

Comment: Nayefc: why it worked in jsfiddle: likely because jsfiddle's not a browser and does not have a default stylesheet? I think fiddle is best  used as a sort of paste-bin and never for actual testing.

Answer (score 3):

See the fiddle for demo and if you remove the value div will not shrink.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RFN2h/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RFN2h/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

If CSS works on JS Fiddle and does not work in browsers, you likely have other CSS from the browser defaults or on your page that is hampering the CSS you posted. You could figure out what CSS is being overriden. This can easily be done with say Firebug or Chrome Web Developer. (overriden CSS is striked through).

Likely, the browser is imposing default paddings or margins for paragraphs. You could reset any browser CSS with any of the tactics listed on this page. http://www.cssreset.com/